# IIS7.5 Not Compiling Code

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have just upgraded to using IIS7.5 to host websites on localhost. However, the dynamic compiling of ASP.NET is not working for any web site. I have checked the C:\windows\microsoftnet\framework... etc temp directory, and no compiled files are being created. This dynamic compile worked fine in the basic install of IIS5.0 (my previous version), but does not in IIS7.5 (both running ASP.Net2.0). Is there a setting I'm missing?I've worked for hours on this, and can't seem to find any information that is helpful on how to fix this error.

***Info***

IIS7.5

ASP.NET 2.0

Windows 7 Desktop

All code is .cs in App_Code folder

Page directives look like `<%@ Page Language="C#" inherits="namespacename.codename" %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found at [IIS7.5 Not Compiling Code From App_Code folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863107/iis7-5-not-compiling-code-from-app-code-folder).

Credit goes to @mbmemb.

IIS7.0 does not support APP_CODE in virtual directories. Subdirectories in the root APP_CODE folder indicating the virtual directory they belong too must be used.

Answer (score 2):

First, check Handler Mappings on the site, makes sure ASPX, ASCX and other ASP.NET extensions are mapped to %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll (if your app pool is configured in classic mode). Also click on Request Restrictions and make sure Script option is selected on Access tab.

If you don't see ASP.NET extensions, the ASP.NET IIS feature is not present and needs to be installed via Server Manager on server OS or Programs and Features on desktop OS.

Then, make sure your application pool is configured to run .NET 2.0. Since you are coming from IIS 5, try setting the pipeline mode to "classic".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Handler Mappings has aspx covered. That is the only asp.net file extension I'm using. I've assured the app pool is correct as well. I cannot find "Request Restrictions". Where is this located?

Comment: I've added some info above as well that may help the situation.

Comment: Do you see an error when browsing aspx pages?

Can you try putting CodeFile attributes in page directives.

Also, to test the compiler you can try pre-compiling from command line:
Aspnet_compiler -v /WebApplication1
Aspnet_compiler.exe is located in .NET install folder.